# Update a class instance's __dict__ by another class instance

Tags: python

I have the following question:
My python scripts parses .pdf documents and return found order information as an instance of this class:

```
@dataclass
class BasicOrder:
    order_id: str = ''   
    supplier_name: str = ''     
    supplier_order_id: str = ''
    client_order_id: str = ''
    base_name: str = ''
    container_no: str = ''  
    seal_no: str = ''
```

However, more often than not document don't have complete order information, so I have to query the database to find if there is more information.

So I end up with two objects: of BasicOrder class: **order_from_pdf** and **order_from_db**, one have some attributes filled (for example `container_no` and `seal_no`), other have `order_id, supplier_name`, etc. (what is known from pdf and db can be very random, since different documents have different data and not always filled correctly)

Finally, I have to 'smash' them together into one complete object, I use this function:

```
    def update_dict(self, another_object_dict: dict):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if not value and another_object_dict[key]:
                self.__dict__[key] = another_object_dict[key]
```

Here is the question: can I somehow pass another object instance instead of **dict**?
It gives me `Unresolved reference 'BasicOrder'` if to use it as an argument.

Or maybe there is more 'clean' way to do this?

**Solution found:** after some consideration, I've decided that to have class method that updates itself by another instance is kinda dumb, insdead I just create new fused order after I've got pdf and db version inside the method that does comparison. That, IMO is the cleanest solution here.

Comment: There should be a single method `create_order` which takes both a PDF file *and* a database as arguments, and returns a complete instance of `BasicOrder`. Don't create two incomplete orders.

Comment: Use `None` to indicate the absence of an optional field. Only use `''` if it's *legal* value for the field. Don't use either to indicate it wasn't available from a particular source.

Comment: You can use `dataclasses` and `typing` modules to solve your problem. Use dataclass with Optional fields.

Comment: @Kaz oh it is a dataclass, I forgot to copy dataclass decordator, will edit it ASAP. Thanks for hint tho.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the advice about None!

Comment: *There should be a single method create_order which takes both a PDF file and a database as arguments, and returns a complete instance of BasicOrder. Don't create two incomplete orders.* @chepner 
Yeah, but I don't wan't to have this class to be able to parse pdfs and query databases, since it is not its job, it is just an order representation.

Comment: `BasicOrder(**pdf_dict, **db_dict)`?

Comment: It's not the job of `BasicOrder.__init__`. It *can* be the job of a class method that collects the necessary information from a PDF and a database to pass to `BasicOrder.__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `asdict` function from dataclasses rather than `__dict__` to make sure you have no side effects. Here is small example:

```
import dataclasses
from typing import Optional


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    attr_1: str
    attr_2: Optional[int] = None
    attr_3: Optional[str] = None
    
    def combine_with_other(self, other: "Foo") -> "Foo":
        attribute_dict_other = dataclasses.asdict(other)
        attribute_dict_self = dataclasses.asdict(self)
        merged_dict = {
            key: attribute_dict_other[key] if attribute is None else attribute 
            for key, attribute in attribute_dict_self.items()
        }
        return Foo(**merged_dict)
```

here is the output:

```
>>> db_version = Foo("foo", attr_3="attr_3")
>>> local_version = Foo("foo", 42)
>>> print(local_version.combine_with_other(db_version))
Foo(attr_1='foo', attr_2=42, attr_3='attr_3')
```

Comment: for me when I try to other: Foo, it gives me `Unresolved reference 'Foo' ` warning and `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`. The same as with my class, before passing the `another_object_dict` I wanted to pass the instance of the same class itself, but run into this error, that is the reason I've created this post in the first place.

Comment: sorry about that I think this is due to the typing, you can try using string versions of the type. This might depend on the version of python. I have updated the answer, if it still doesn't work, can you share your python version for further investigation

Comment: I use Python 3.9

Comment: I have tested the updated version with python 3.7.11 and it seems to work (had your error in python 3.7 as well). Is the error still present with the updated typing info?

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is working perfectly!